# Remove 8 char, save 4, remove 4, save 4, replace 1 and keep rest of the line

Tags: regex, notepad++, textpad

In every line I would like to:

- remove char 1-8 (8)
- save char 9-12 (4)
- remove char 13-16 (4)
- save char 17-20 (4)
- replace char 21 (1) with space
- keep the rest of line

and then do it for every line

I have started with:

^.{8}(.{4}).{4}

Is it possible to in oneline or repeat the pattern...

(I use Notepad++ and TextPad)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick. Simply count the characters as you've done and replace with the capture groups and a space.

**Find**

```
^.{8}(.{4}).{4}(.{4})(.{1})
```

**Replace** (incl. the space after `$2`)

```
$1$2
```

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/e0b5d392caaaccfb8747cc15e37e3e96.gif]

Comment: `{1}` is superfluous and there is also no need to capture the last character, as you wont use it. Apart from that, that's how I would do it too.

Comment: TIL you can use `$1` in the replace, I always used `\1`

Comment: I used:

`^.{8}(.{4}).{4}(.{5})(.{1})(.{1})`
and preplaced it with: 

`\1\2 `

with a "space" after "2" which solved my problem in my problem.